# How can I update a property on a list of grails domain objects?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have a list of domain class objects:

```
def books = Books.findAllByTitleLike("%Hobbit%")
```

Now I want to update the property "available" in all books in this list. Normally, I would do

```
books.each {
   it.available = false;
   it.save()
}
```

Is there a better way to do that? Should I do it in one transaction? Like:

```
Book.withTransaction { ... }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bulk update using executeUpdate

```
def updatedRecords = Book.executeUpdate("update Book set available = 'false' where title like'%Hobbit%' ")
```

Per comments:
Its hql and its similar to sql.

This is another way you can do it (inner query):

```
def sql = """update Domain
set $fieldName = '$fieldValue'
where id in (select id from Domain1 where seqId = '$myid')"""
def updatedRecords = Domain.executeUpdate(sql)
```

Or 
Something in this line:

```
"... where id in ('123','132','111')
```

I have not tested this but you might be able to say

```
def list= ['123','132','111']
" ... where id in ($list)"
```

Comment: I updated the book list, because I do not want to update all Brooks, but only a few. So how can I pass this list of books to your query?

Comment: you can add where clause to query string. Like "where x=1 or x=2" something like this. you might even be able to use inList, not sure if inlist works for it but you can give it a shot. But generally you are flexible to build you own query sql like.

Comment: just noticed you updated your question, you should be able to use like as well. I made a change to my answer see if it works.

Comment: Suppose you have a list of ids how should you query?